# hibernate bidirectional one-to-one mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I am trying to figure out how to define an one to one relation given the below prerequisites /note there is no reference to Activity in the Schedule class/. I can't get both keys to be inserted. I looked here [one-to-one](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-bidirectional-121) but still can't get it to work - the Schedule primary key in Activity doesn't get inserted:

there are 2 tables:

```
activity table
activity_id
name
...
schedule (fk schedule)
```

---

```
schedule table
schedule id
name
..
activity_id(fk activity)
```

---

pojos:

```
class Activity{
private int activity_id;
private String name;
private Schedule schedule;

..
getters + setters
}
```

---

```
class Schedule{
private int schedule_id;
private String name;
..
getters + setters
}
```

Comment: The activity_id column in the schedule table doesn't serve any purpose. It's redendant with the activity.schedule column. Why don't you simply remove it?

Comment: If he did, wouldn't that create a one-to-many relationship, rather than a one-to-one?

Comment: unfortunately I can't change the db schema or the pojos... (ownership issue)

Comment: You can try hibernates @Formula. Note that it's not JPA compliant and uses SQL expressions (not SQL).